# nuxt 3 : generate and host a small pwa

Tags: progressive-web-apps, nuxtjs3, hosted

I'm testing Nuxt 3 (RC for now), and really love it.

I made a very small front-end application ( no backend, 3 pages, a complex form with some formulas to display some results ).

it works nice locally, there is nothing related to backend, so
I obviously could used only Vue,

but for testing purpose and to go further, I would like to generate a PWA, host it on a dev server ( in a subfolder ) and try to install it on my phone.
It seems nuxt-pwa is not still compatible with nuxt 3,
according to this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt-community/pwa-module/issues/492), I've installed [kevinmarrec/nuxt-pwa-module](https://github.com/kevinmarrec/nuxt-pwa-module),

It works partially ( well.. favion and icons is generated locally )
but I don't know how to configure nuxt.config.js:

- the router didn't match the subfolder,
- no styles or reactivity is working, I got only my html displayed
- I don't even know which command to use : npm run build or generate

I've looked a couple of hours, unsuccesfully, so is there someone knowing some good resources explaining how to turn a Nuxt 3 app into PWA and solve my silly problems

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey sorry for the late reply, but the API is similar to that of `nuxt/pwa` meaning configuration from [nuxt/pwa](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org) will most likely work with the module. To confirm try adding the following `pwa` config to your `nuxt.config.js` and check if it works

```js
meta: {
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: "Some juicy description",
      theme_color: "#dddddd",
},
```

Note: the `name` property changes the title of the page. The description adds a meta `description` tag and the theme_color adds a meta `theme-color` tag

You can find out more from https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/meta

Any of the commands `build` or `generate` will work, but preferably `build`